# Why was Ahmadi's account suspended?

Tags: discussion

He seemed to know many things and had helped the site grow a lot. Was it something specific?

Just curious.

Comment: See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, moderators are **not allowed to publicly discuss suspensions** or the reasons for them. It's part of the moderator agreement as well as the moderator culture.

From my end: per my observations, Ahmadi had plenty of knowledge and perspective to offer -- but he wasn't able to do so in a constructive, non-combative way for any extended amount of time. Despite extensive warnings, handholding, and guidance, he chose to ignore the help offered to him and continue his problematic behavior.

I don't have the full details on why he was suspended, but my observations are likely in line with the moderators' reasoning.

Comment: Since I can't comment on specifics, I can say that Aarthi is correct. Ahmadi is a user with both a high rep (lots of useful content to share) but his share of troubles and clashes with the SE system and how to share it constructively.

Comment: i see. anyways, its sad to see such a useful contributor being barred. it would be nice, if minimally, the penalty period is reduced. i think having him back in action will help this site make it out of beta faster. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @Nerrve as Aarthi mentioned, he wasn't able to share it constructively *for any extended amount of time.* That's really the key here. This is not his first ban, and a ban is always a last attempt after trying several other ways and several other times to warn and curb unwelcome behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

I think Ahmadi punishment is too severe. Having him banned for one year in my view is too much of a punishment.

While I am not aware of exact circumstances why he was banned, I am aware that he was to some what pushy in Shia sect agenda. But then he had asked a lot of good question and had many good answers. For that reason he overall left a positive impact on this site. I wouldn't say it was overly positive but then I do not know much.

I am up for removing his ban. The reason is I have not seen any behavior problem with his participation on the forum. To me behavior/etiquette problem is strictly no no and must sure be banned. But I have not seen any problem with him. If he was too strong of a believer in his particular faith, that is condonable and if he did something wrong, punishment is ok as long as it is reasonable.

I wish he can come back on the site.